# Scripting In photoshop and Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-scripting, illustrator-scripting

I'm a graphic designer, but I have never been into coding, now I want to learn Scripting for adobe programs like photoshop and illustrator, What would be a good place for a non developer to start learning scripting for these programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following links I hope it will give you a jump start

[Introduction To Photoshop Scripting](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/25/introduction-to-photoshop-scripting/)

[10 Photoshop Scripting Tutorials](http://slodive.com/photoshop/photoshop-scripting-tutorials/)

Also you can check adobe official Scripting Guid.
(Just Google "Photoshop Developer Center scripting" and it should be from the top results if not the first :) )